# Sort nested list objects

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I have the following task. I have a list of objects (Album) which contains fields and a list with another object (Song). I need to sort both album and song lists with their properties. What I tried so far

```
albumList.onEach { it.songs.sortedByDescending { song -> song.isFavorite} 
.sortedByDescending { it.createDate }
```

As a result, the album list is sorted by it's createDate property but songs list doesn't. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Is the list of songs property a `val` or a `var`? Is it a `MutableList` or read-only `List`?

Comment: `sortedBy` creates a new sorted list, but does not modify the original list. You need either a MutableList and use `sortBy` instead of `sortedBy`. Or you need the songs list to be a `var` and you set the result of the `sortedBy` call back to the original property to change it.

Comment: Thank for a quick reply. My both lists are immutable. In that case why does it sort the album list but not the nested one?

Comment: I don't know how you're checking that it's sorted, but `sortedBy` always creates a new List instance.

Comment: Is field `createDate` in `Album` or `Song`? Are you planning to sort albums by `createDate`, and songs in EACH of album sort by `isFavorite` (so favourites first).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some "dirty" solution. I'm not so happy with that, but it works.

```
val newList: List<Album> = albumList
    // Sort albums
    .sortedWith(compareBy { it.createDate })
    // Sort songs inside each of albums
    .map { album ->
        album.apply {
            // Assign NEW list
            songs = album.songs.sortedWith(compareBy { it.isFavorite })
        }
    }
```

## How it works:

1) Sort albums by date of creation `createDate`

2) For each of albums:

- get all `songs`
- map them to itself but only with `songs` sorting (assign sorted `songs` to `songs` field, so it has to be `var` not `val`)

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort the parent list, and then create a new list by using `map` on the first list, and inside it, you can use the `copy` function to set the sorted inner list.

```kotlin
val tempList: List<Album> = albumList
    .sortedWith(compareBy { it.createDate })
val newList = tempList.map { album ->
    val sortedSongs = album.songs.sortedWith(compareBy { it.isFavorite })
    album.copy(songs = sortedSongs)
}
```

This way, you can prevent using `var` instead of `val` :)